# Form variable for django CreateView

Tags: python, django, variables

Heads-Up: I don't know if this is a duplicate, but all the questions that StackOverflow said to be similar are not mine.

Hi, I have a django model called Post (I am doing the usual 'blog' website, since I am still learning). I am creating a CreateView for it (django.views.generic) to create more posts.

My problem is that I want to pass in `string` as a context variable. This can be done with `context_object_name` or the function `get_context_data`. But, to create the form that CreateView automatically generates, it passes a context variable called `form`. Since I am passing my own context data, the CreateView's `form` context variable gets overwritten.

So, what I am asking is, what is the name of that `form` variable (if there is) that I can pass into the context data dictionary like `{'string': my_string, form: createView_form_variable}`.

CreateView:

```
class CreateBlogView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogs/create_update_blogs.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self):
        return {'string': 'Create', 'form': This is the thing I need}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated - Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please comment if I have not made things clear

Comment: Do you not call `super` when you override the form? [Edit] and show your code...

Comment: could you show how to implement this with the function get_context_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `get_context_data` will return a dictionary to be passed as a context. The problem with your implementation is that you aren't calling the `super` method and using it's returned value. `super` is used to call the same method of the *parent* class, hence you can write:

```
class CreateBlogView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blogs/create_update_blogs.html'
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)  # call super
        context['string'] = 'Create'  # add to the returned dictionary
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Aziz Barkat, this has worked. Thanks for the quick response too.